# How to properly make client server talk in java?

Tags: java, javafx, server, client, javafx-11

https://pastebin.com/GMKQHXnQ

https://pastebin.com/tJ51QHrv

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Client extends Application {

   static DataOutputStream toServer = null;
   static DataInputStream fromServer = null;
   public TextField field;
   public static TextArea area;
   public BorderPane mainPane;
   static Button topLeft;
   static Button topMid;
   static Button topRight;
   static Button midLeft;
   static Button midMid;
   static Button midRight;
   static Button botLeft;
   static Button botMid;
   static Button botRight;

   private BorderPane borderPane;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       // UI
       BorderPane fieldPane = new BorderPane();
       fieldPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
       fieldPane.setLeft(new Label("Enter text: "));

       field = new TextField();
       field.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
       fieldPane.setCenter(field);

       BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
       area = new TextArea();
       area.setEditable(false);
       mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(area));
       mainPane.setTop(fieldPane);

       TextArea output = new TextArea();
       output.setWrapText(true);
       GridPane gamePane = new GridPane();
       gamePane.addRow(2);
       gamePane.addColumn(2);
       gamePane.setHgap(250);
       gamePane.setVgap(250);

       topLeft = new Button();
       topLeft.setMinSize(60, 60);
       topMid = new Button();
       topMid.setMinSize(60, 60);
       topRight = new Button();
       topRight.setMinSize(60, 60);
       midLeft = new Button();
       midLeft.setMinSize(60, 60);
       midMid = new Button();
       midMid.setMinSize(60, 60);
       midRight = new Button();
       midRight.setMinSize(60, 60);
       botLeft = new Button();
       botLeft.setMinSize(60, 60);
       botMid = new Button();
       botMid.setMinSize(60, 60);
       botRight = new Button();
       botRight.setMinSize(60, 60);
       gamePane.add(topLeft, 0, 0);
       gamePane.add(topMid, 0, 1);
       gamePane.add(topRight, 0, 2);
       gamePane.add(midLeft, 1, 0);
       gamePane.add(midMid, 1, 1);
       gamePane.add(midRight, 1, 2);
       gamePane.add(botLeft, 2, 0);
       gamePane.add(botMid, 2, 1);
       gamePane.add(botRight, 2, 2);
       mainPane.setCenter(gamePane);
       mainPane.setTop(output);
       // Create a serverScene and place it in the stage
       output.setText("Server Started");

       Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Client");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
// END UI


       try { // start connect
           Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8182);

           fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
           toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           area.appendText(e.toString() + '\n');
       }

       field.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {/*
               String normal = this.field.getText();

               toServer.writeUTF(normal);
               toServer.flush();

               String inverse = fromServer.readUTF();
               area.appendText("Inverse from the server is: " + inverse + '\n');*/
           } catch (Exception e2) {
               area.appendText(e2.toString() + '\n');
           }
       });
       topLeft.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(1);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               area.appendText(ioException.toString() + '\n');
           }
       });
       topMid.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(2);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       topRight.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(3);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       midLeft.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(4);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       midMid.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(5);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       midRight.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(6);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       botLeft.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(7);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       botMid.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(8);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       botRight.setOnAction(e -> {
           try {
               try {
                   sendMove.send(9);
               } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                   interruptedException.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException ioException) {
               ioException.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
}
class sendMove{

public static void send(int i) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
       Client.toServer.write(i);
       Client.toServer.flush();
       Platform.runLater(()->{

       int inverse=0;
       try{
       inverse=Client.fromServer.readInt();
       }catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }

       Client.area.appendText(inverse+" recieved back");
       });
       Thread.sleep(100);
       }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Server extends Application {

    private int clientNo = 0;
    private TextArea ta = new TextArea();

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ta.setEditable(false);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta), 450, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
        primaryStage.show();

        new Thread( () -> {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8182);

                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    ta.appendText("Server started time " + new Date() + '\n');
                });

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientNo++;

                    Platform.runLater( () -> {
                        ta.appendText("Starting client " + clientNo + " at " + new Date() + '\n');
                        ta.appendText("Client " + clientNo + " IP Address is " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + '\n');
                    });

                    new Thread(new ThreadClient(socket)).start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ta.appendText(e.toString() + '\n');
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class ThreadClient implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;

        public ThreadClient(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run () {
            try {
                DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                while (true) {
                    int normal = inputFromClient.readInt();
                    int inverse = normal;

                    outputToClient.write(inverse);

                    Platform.runLater( () -> {
                        ta.appendText("Text received from client: " + normal + '\n');
                        ta.appendText("Inverse is " + inverse + '\n');
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ta.appendText(e.toString() + '\n');
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here are both bits of code

Problem:

Clicking a button freezes client completely, no errors given

General idea:

was to click a button, sends to the server, sever sends back to both clients. Clients use the number to disable corresponding button, add some text and editing and boom, tic tac toe.